# Rails, Apache, Thin on Windows. Better configuration for httpd.conf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, apache, thin

I'm using this configuration with the lines in this good answer ([Rails Deployment Environment on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252199/rails-deployment-environment-on-windows)):

```
<VirtualHost *:82>

  # Your server's web or IP address goes here.
  # You can leave at localhost if deploying to
  # company intranet or some such thing.
  ServerName localhost

  # Customize the next two lines with your app's public directory
  DocumentRoot "C:/RubyStack-3.2.5-0/projects/app_name/public"
  <Directory "C:/RubyStack-3.2.5-0/projects/app_name/public">
    Allow from all
    Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>

  RewriteEngine On

  # Redirect all non-static requests to Rails server,
  # but serve static assets via Apache
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ balancer://app_balancers%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,L]

  # Serves dynamic rails assets from multiple servers
  # to improve performance. A Rails server such as
  # thin or WEBrick must be running on at least one of
  # these ports in order for Apache to serve your site
  <Proxy balancer://app_balancers>
    BalancerMember http://localhost:3001/
    BalancerMember http://localhost:3002/
  </Proxy>

  # Support for far-futures expires header
  <LocationMatch "^/assets/.*$">
    Header unset ETag
    FileETag None
    # RFC says only cache for 1 year
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
  </LocationMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

But browsing, I found other articles and other questions of other people who have configured Apache httpd in a different way, by adding or subtracting configuration lines.

Like here: http://www.varyonic.com/2011/06/using-apache-with-mongrel-or-thin-and-rails-3/#.VK5OhyuG9G6

What is it?:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On  
    ProxyPass /images !  
    ProxyPass /stylesheets !  
    ProxyPass /javascripts !  
    ProxyPass / balancer://thinservers/  
    ProxyPassReverse / balancer://thinservers/
```

Now, of course, I'm here to ask you: what is best for Rails 4 on Windows 8.1 / Windows 10?

The server Thin is the best for Windows 8.1/10? Mongrel? Other?

Alternatives to Apache for stability and speed?

The operating system is Windows and I can not change it.

Comment: any luck ever figuring this out? I am in a similar situation trying to deploy to windows with apache, deciding on a web server