# How to deploy a rails application on Windows PC (windows 7 / windows 8)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, vagrant, virtualbox

I have built a rails app which is used as a standalone enterprise application. The application needs to run on Windows desktops (entire user base runs Windows machines). I am able to run it quite successfully on an Ubuntu machine but it's not something customers will prefer to run.

Since deploying on a windows machine is [quite messy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252199/rails-deployment-environment-on-windows) AFAIK. I would like deploy it on Windows using a virtual machine (VirtualBox).

Requirements would be -

1. Application installation on Windows 7 / Windows 8.
2. User should be able to access rails server by browser running on his/her system via localhost or any other IP address.
3. Application should auto-start when user reboots the machine.
4. Ideally user should be able to download and install the software on his/her machine by himself/herself.

I am working to make this work but would like to know the feasibility of this solution. Would like to if I am getting the concepts wrongs or if there is something which is simply not possible or is not making any sense.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I am a huge fan of  Ruby and Ruby on Rails, but it sounds like you chose the wrong development platform. What happens when you have an update to your code; are you going to go around to every single computer and update it? What happens when they want to share data from one instance to data of another instance?

Comment: Right now I don't have enough resources to build the app on any other platform due to my constraints like my knowledge / time / money. If I can make it work on windows this way it would solve my problem. Since it's a enterprise software it doesn't require frequent updates and the requirements are quite limited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Vagrant](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/cli/index.html), which is a highly scriptable VM host. You can then generate batch files to automatically start the VM on boot.

To deploy new code, you'll just want to provide them with a new VM image they can copy into your app directory.

That said, I agree with other comments that this might not be the right platform for your use case. The main reason for building web apps is so that many clients can use your app over the web using just one set of servers. Deploying a web server to each client seems like it's defeating that advantage.

Comment: Vagrant sounds like a great idea to me. Will try this out. Thanks.