# Deploy Ruby on Rails application in a Windows Server 2012

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, apache

I have read about how to deploy a Ruby on Rails in Windows, some of them about Windows Server and IIS. 
I downloaded Rubyinstaller and its Dev-Kit in my developer pc to develop my application, however I don't know how to use it with Apache instead the embed WEBrick server. Some people have pointed that using Passenger Gem is not a good idea in terms of performance, but those posts that I found are before 2012 or older.

I would like to know how to deploy **a RoR application (Rails 4.x, Ruby 2.x) in a production server with Windows Server 2012 and XAMPP** (Apache), without breaking most of the current configuration, preferably **not using IIS.**

I also found a Bitnami installer with the Ruby Stack. I could customize the installation deselecting those components that I already have or I don't need, like Git, PHP, MySQL, etc. but installation of Apache in this installer is mandatory, so, is there any chance to avoid breaking my current installation/configuration of Apache (installed by another Bitnami XAMPP installer)? I already have an Apache/PHP installation that I don't want to break.

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252199/rails-deployment-environment-on-windows) help at all?

Comment: Mostly. I make it work in local, but that may break my current production configuration.

Comment: Can you elaborate? What might break? Or do you really just not know what may break?

Comment: I simulated a production environment in my own local machine by setting `rails_env = production` environment variable and all that stuff. I had to configure a VirtualHost for a reverseproxy to Thin webserver, but that broke the configuration and made the other PHP site inaccessible. I had to create another VirtualHost for the PHP site. Both sites works in that way, the problem is in the production server PHP applications are accessible just by `mysite.com/myapp` with no additional config, no different ports, I'm afraid that config may brake that.

Comment: Is there a reason it must run under apache ? I supose you don't need to loadbalace or something like that ? The easiest thing is to run Rails as a windows service, you would only have to take care not to use ports than those allready in use by IIS or Apache. I run several Sinatra apps thsi way along with Tomcats and IIS. I succeeded once configuring a Sinatra app under apache in a Bitnami stack but I had to experiment a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirements I would run the app in Docker on azure/windows server.

Or try puma, using this windows install tutorial https://github.com/hicknhack-software/rails-disco/wiki/Installing-puma-on-windows.

Comment: I don't like so much the idea of running a VM in server... :/

Comment: Mind if I ask why? We run docker and really like. It makes deploys pretty easy and has a good security story. That said, it isn't for everyone.

Comment: I've never used Docker, I like the idea of having the same stack in different OSes. I worked in a past project with developers using MacOS X and me testing on a CentOS server. When I heard about Docker later, I thought that could be helpful at that time. I would like to implement it in future projects but in other servers... The problem is the feature that I like of Docker is that you don't need VMs, is not present in Windows. When you install stuff like VirtualBox, you have to reboot your host after install. I'm unable to this in our production server.

Comment: Fair. So, I've used passenger and it's quite nice, and I like puma too.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you'd just use Docker and run the app in a linux container to avoid all the potential problems. However, since Windows Server 2012 lacks native support for containers, I don't think you can have Docker running directly on this windows server.

So, instead, I'd suggest adding an extra layer in between - deploying a linux VM which has Docker installed and contains a Docker image which contains your application to the windows server.

Answer (score 0):

The are a couple of ways I see fit is to host your app in IIS. The only problem is that IIS does not have a native way to host Rails app. OPTION 1 - We used Rails on an existing IIS web infrastructure using Mongrel:http://www.napcsweb.com/howto/rails/deployment/railsonIISWithMongrel.pdf

Or

Option 2 using Mongrel without IIS like so:

1. install rails and mongrel

   `gem install rails –include-dependencies
   gem install mongrel –include-dependencies`
2. serve rails app

`rails app` 
or 
`ruby server 0e production -p 4001`
check you can acceess the site
press ctrl-c to exit

3. Install Mongrel as a service

`mongrel_rails_service install –n rails_app –p 4001`

start the *rails_app* service from services.msc

From the original rails documentation you have more options to host your ruby app on production:
http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2006/5/11/deploying-rails-on-windows-servers/