# RoR not loading on Windows Server 2012 with IIS 8 and HttpPlatformHandler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2, httpplatformhandler

Navigating to 127.0.0.1/rails spawns ruby.exe when looking through the Process Explorer, they quickly disappear and the page never loads. Leads me to believe that there is something wrong with my config file.

---

I am following along with [Running Ruby on Rails on IIS8 with HttpPlatformHandler](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AnnouncingRunningRubyOnRailsOnIIS8OrAnythingElseReallyWithTheNewHttpPlatformHandler.aspx) and I hit a wall.

I have verified that Rails can run a application under the local WEBrick server. However, I cannot figure out why a application will not launch under IIS8. I am hoping someone out there can help me verify a few things or point me in the right direction. In the blog, Scott is running Windows 8. So, perhaps there are some differences that I am missing by using Windows Server 2012.

**Windows Features**

In the blog, Scott simply turns Internet Information Services on. On the server, it seems a bit more involved. I have installed:

1. Application Server:

   - .NET Framework 4.5
   - Web Server (IIS) Support
2. Web Server (IIS)

   - Web Server

     - Common HTTP Features
     - Application Development

Perhaps someone out there could verify that I am not missing anything in that section. I can elaborate further if necessary.

**web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="httpplatformhandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
        </handlers>
        <httpPlatform stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile="rails.log" startupTimeLimit="20" processPath="c:\Ruby22-x64\bin\ruby.exe"
                  arguments="&quot;C:\Ruby22-x64\bin\rails&quot; server -p %HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT% -b 127.0.0.1">
        </httpPlatform>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Thank you for taking a look! Any input would be very much appreciated! I realize serving a Rails application on Windows is not ideal. However, I am not left with any other choice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that my original problem boiled down to user account control issues. But that was taking to long to get resolved, so I took a different path.

I ended up using Apache. This answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252199/rails-deployment-environment-on-windows) was very helpful.

Rough outline of steps I took:

1. Install Ruby, DevKit, Rails and make sure they run

   - Make sure your application can run locally
2. Create .bat files that start your server. Convert them to .exe's. Then create a service start them with [nssm](https://nssm.cc/).
3. Setup and configure Apache

   - Edit your httpd.conf file

     - Make sure you have the necessary modules installed. You can use Apache error logs to troubleshoot this step.
     - Include vhosts if you opt to use that.

       - Edit vhosts file so it points to your application.